Removing sharp edges on a bamboo desktop

I purchased this desk online: https://www.vwindesk.com/products/vwindesk-72-x-30-x-1-inch-100-solid-bamboo-desk-table-top-only-for-standing-desk-home-office-desk-with-60mm-grommetsright-angle
My previous desktop had rounded edges where my arms rest. This new desktop has a sharp edge as seen in the image I linked. It digs into my arms/wrist when I rest my arms on it. Is it possible to sand this edge down?

Can you give us a pic showing the edge at the narrow end? I think the answer is yes, but sometimes veneers are weird.

Hi, welcome to StackExchange. "Can I sand this edge down? If so, how do I get started? Is it easy enough for someone like me to do on their own?" This is three queries, and while they are of course related the model on SE is one query per Question. In essence every Q here should only have a single ? in the body text. The how-to portion is quite separate from the can I?/is it possible? portion, and should be asked separately but only after you've done independent research and then only if you cannot find what you need, or some clarification is needed. [contd]

...There is as you can imagine quite a bit of sanding advice here already if you want to start here, but there's buckets of sanding guidance to be found online.


Is it possible to sand this edge down?

Yes, if the desktop is solid as per the description on the website.
Bamboo is quite hard, but just "easing the edge" as we say — removing the sharpness on edges (more accurately, arrises) to make them more comfortable to touch or brush against — can be as simple as a few swipes with a suitable sanding block. Literally just 2-3 swipes is enough to go from a really uncomfortable arris to something pleasant to interact with.
However you mention your previous desk had actual rounded edges. Creating true 'roundovers' is also feasible using hand sanding only, but will take longer. How long is simply dependent on the radius needed (larger radius = lots more material to remove) and the sanding material(s) chosen.
As it's a lot more work to create a substantial roundover (especially over a length of 72") I would suggest you do this only to the top-front edge and merely ease the rest if they need it, which as I say above is easily accomplished with only a few swipes. You'll be done on the other seven arrises in only a minute or so.
In terms of the process you'd use, you can follow the planing advice in the image in this previous Answer, What hand tools to use for rounding edges and creating pockets? and just swap in a sanding block for the plane.
There's a paragraph immediately underneath with some sanding advice. One detail missing is that you're probably best doing this with the abrasive paper backed by a hard block of some kind, however you could do this with a commercial foam sanding block which are now widely available where sanding supplies are sold. This simplifies what you need to buy and could be substantially cheaper (abrasive papers are usually sold it packs, which is much more sandpaper than you'd need for this one project).

I would add that for someone with no experience looking to achieve a more substantial roundover, a rasp (or rasps, coarse then fine) followed by sandpaper might be the easiest option. Decent rasps can be bought for little money (e.g. Shinto rasp) and don’t need to be sharpened, unlike handplanes. Sharpening requires yet more gear and is difficult to learn.

@stanch, not sure whether I'd class $20-34 (possibly with shipping on top) as "little money" in this context. I'm a huge proponent of rasps (conventional, unconventional and radical, like the Shintos) and one or more is a great suggestion for any aspiring woodworker, but is perhaps overkill for a possible/likely one-timer.

Fair enough! I guess my point of comparison was a handplane + sharpening media, which is even more overkill. This is all assuming a substantial roundover is needed. I’d pay $20-34 to not have to sand for hours :P

"I guess my point of comparison was a handplane + sharpening media, which is even more overkill." Absolutely! Even with a super-budget sharpening option (all-in at under 20 bucks) and the cheapest viable plane I can think of (i.e. not a Kobalt) it would be substantially more. "I’d pay $20-34 to not have to sand for hours" Indeed. But assuming it is just the one arris that requires the full roundover treatment I would hope it won't take literal hours. Or to put it another way, if it does take that long one is doing it wrong ^_^
